# ¿Como identificar cuando input file no tiene nada seleccionado?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input-file

Estoy creando un método que realiza la subida de un archivo, pero el **`input` file** es generado y ejecutado por otro `button`

1. Click al button
2. Se crea un input para recibir el archivo
3. Después de generar el `input` file, ejecuta  `click()`
4. Se empieza una carga, en espera de la selección del archivo
5. Teniendo el archivo, empiezo subida al server
6. Espero respuesta del server y muestro resultado

El siguiente ejemplo muestra un intento utilizando el `document.body.onfocus` el cual lamentablemente se ejecuta antes del `onChange` lo cual detecta en todas las ocasiones que no hay un archivo seleccionado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onClick='handleUpload()'>ejecutar selectFile</button>
  <input type="file" id="selectFile" />
</body>
<script>
        
  const handleUpload = async () => {
  console.log('Cargando...');
  const input = document.getElementById('selectFile');
  input.click();
  
  try {
    const selectedFile = await new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      try {
        let file;

        input.onchange = (e) => {
          file = e.target.files;
          resolve(file[0]);
        };
        input.onclick = (e) =>{
          console.log('ejecutando onClick');
        }
        input.onblur = (e) => {
          console.log('onBlur');
        };
        input.onfocus = (e) => {
          console.log('focus input = ', e);
        };
        document.body.onfocus = (ev) => {
          console.info('ejecutando onFocus', file);
          if (!file) {
            reject(file);
          }
          resolve(file);
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error input');
      }
    });

    console.log('Finalizo carga');

    if (!selectedFile) {
      console.error('Archivo no seleccionado');
      return;
    }
  } catch (errorCatch) {
    console.log('finalizo carga con error', e);
  }
};

</script>
</html>
```

El error es que no puedo identificar cundo el usuario no selecciono nada o cuando ya no esta interactuando con la ventana de selección de archivos

he probado ejemplos como [este](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-file-input-using-javascript/)

Comment: La verdad al intentar entender el código y tu pregunta creo que me he liado y cada vez que intentaba leerla me liaba más, mi duda es, porque todo esto te lo ha de decir del lado cliente?? por qué no te lo dice el servidor, mucho más seguro y mucho más fiable.
Es decir, envías un fetch con el archivo, el servidor no recibe archivo, el input no coge archivo el servidor lo recibe, pues premio

Comment: @DavidGonzalo Se busca la menor cantidad de solicitudes o por lo meno las solicitudes que pueden ser validadas por el cliente. trate de poner unicamente lo básico y lo siento demasiado simple el código, la pregunta supongo que tengo que reformular, pero si eres tan amable de indicar que es lo que no se entiende y yo corregir.

Answer (score 0):

No te preocupes, cualquiera puede estancarse o no encontrar respuesta de ningún tipo cuando se realizan validaciones con los input-file.

Cuando realicé validaciones con los input-file, me topé con la misma pregunta, de cuándo saber cuando no se seleccionaba un archivo, y así hice la validación:

1-.Primero creé una función que tomara ese input, tal cuál como lo haces tú, pero le envié el parámetro 'this'. Así lo pude tomar, sin tener que utilizar el **e.target**, que no está mal pero quizás puedas probarlo de esta forma. También que personalmente no lo hice con un **onClick** sino con un **onChange**:

Mi input estaba así:

```
<input type="file" 
       accept=".pdf"
       name="recaudos[]"
       class="custom-file-input inputRecaudo" 
       id="#recaudoId"
       lang="es" 
       onchange="verificarInput(this);">
```

Y mi validación de javascript era de la siguiente estructura:

```
function verificarInput(archivo) {
    if (archivo.files[0] <= 0 
        || archivo.files[0] === null 
        || archivo.files[0] === "" 
        || archivo.files[0] === undefined || archivo.files[0] === "undefined" 
        || archivo.files[0] === "null") {

       cancel = document.getElementById(`recaudoId`);
       if (cancel.value == "" || cancel.value == null) {
        // Codigo en caso de no haber seleccionado archivo
       }

    }
}
```

Lo que requieres verificar es: si es vacio o null, en todo caso, si es así, deja de mostrar la carga.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la intención, pero el evento `onchange` no se ejecuta al menos que halla un cambio, al no seleccionar nada, el `onchange` no se ejecuta y no detecta si hay archivo o no..
aquí un ejemplo donde pruebo tu código. 
https://jsfiddle.net/0psrjw9L/4/

Comment: Tienes razón, pero recuerda que si quieres validar si la persona seleccionó archivo o no, tienes que validar si el input contiene un valor. Entiendo tu punto, pero con el sólo evento onClick() no se logrará, tienes que complementarlo con el onChange().

Comment: es correcto, intento utilizar todo lo que este disponible en el lenguaje para validar, pero ni mesclando `onclick` y `onchange` puedo verificar si contiene un archivo

Comment: me funcionaría todo perfecto si la función no fuera un método asyncrono. lo cual lo hace complicado, por que aparte de esperar la selección o no del archivo, tiene que validar si trae algo y continuar de manera automática con el resto del código, sin intervención del usuario